# When will we have LPDDR4x memory in MBs/MBPs?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

Apple just announced their much expected 16" MBP, which still features DDR4 memory in order to be able to support more than 16GB RAM. I find that a bit disappointing, and am a bit puzzled as to why we still haven't seen a shift to low-power memory on macbooks.

If my understanding is correct, Intel's newer CPUs should in theory support LPDDR4x memory, and that these should provide significant improvements in terms of power usage.

Could someone explain what is the bottleneck in the wider adoption of this technology?

Comment: There was a similar, if more generic question on Super User about this - https://superuser.com/a/1498611/347380 But, to answer "when" or even "if", only Apple can know that.

Comment: Your question borders on off-topic as either opinion-based or something only someone who works at would be able to answer.  You might want to [edit] it to focus less on the 'why didn't Apple do .....' to avoid it being downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: This is off topic for here, since it's asking about Apple's future plans or someone to point out discussion on architecture and manufacturing - not about using Apple products. If you can edit this to be about what problem you face given we don't know Apple's plans - that might be a very good and on topic question.

Comment: I cannot answer as this question has been put on hold... but the actual "bottleneck" here is the fact that your "theory" is incorrect. The Intel CPUs used DO NOT support LPDDR4 memory at all. It won't work no matter what you do. They support only DDR4 and LPDDR3 RAM. Only the 10th gen Intel mobile processors support LPDDR4 - and the new MacBook Pro has a 9th gen CPU.

Comment: @bmike i wish you read beyond the question title... jksoeggard's comment is the kind of answer I was hoping to get. Turns out my understanding was inaccurate...

Comment: @jksoegaard so is it then reasonable to assume that the corresponding 10th gen CPUs are not yet announced?

Comment: No, they have been announced - and a few select models have launched just 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: posdef Thanks for the note and clarification. I've reversed the multiple close votes. If people vote to close again, let's ask on [meta] to review if it's on topic or not. If an answer doesn't get submitted by you or @jksoegaard - it will likely get closed since comments don't expose this far down by default

Answer (score 4):

The actual "bottleneck" here is the fact that your "theory" is incorrect.

The Intel CPUs used do not support LPDDR4 memory at all. It won't work no matter what you do. They support only DDR4 and LPDDR3 RAM. Only the 10th gen Intel mobile processors support LPDDR4 - and the new MacBook Pro has a 9th gen CPU.

The 10th gen Intel mobile processors have been announced and some models have just recently launched - they support the new LPDDR4 RAM, which is almost the only new feature. However, they're not used by Apple yet. It is logical to assume that at some point, Apple will switch to newer CPUs that support newer types of memory - but this time around was not it.